# When interrupted by a call, iOS does not restore your app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am sure that this is a bug.  I was wondering if anyone knew a workaround. The OS does not properly restore your app after it has been interrupted by a phone call. I have tested this on 7.1 and 7.1.1.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Double click the home button and make sure that the native Phone
   application is not running
2. Start your application (or any app for that matter like Apple's App Store app)
3. Call your phone from another phone
4. Answer the phone and then end the call after a few seconds (it is important that the phone is answered, not declined).

When the call ends, the OS should restore your app to the foreground.  However, what actually happens it that the native Phone app is shown with the Favorites tab selected.

The log shows the following error message:

*May 12 17:33:36 iPhone MobilePhone[146] : Application tried to push a nil view controller on target .*

Everything works fine if the native Phone app is already in the background when a call is received.

I will be submitting a bug report to Apple. In the mean time, is anyone aware of a workaround?

**Edit:**

It's important that the native phone app is terminated (when you double click the home button, it should not show up in the list).  It is also important to actually accept the call, let it connect, and then disconnect.

I am able to reproduce it on both of my devices (AT&T iPhone 4s, Verizon iPhone 4s) even after restoring the devices.  Is anyone else able to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I followed your steps exactly with the app store app and 7.1.1 and was unable to reproduce. The app store app was restored after the call and there was no error message in the log.

Comment: I'm also unable to reproduce.  I wonder if you have some specific settings on your test device.  Does the issue persist after restoring the device?

Comment: I just tested it again after restoring my phone, and I can reproduce the issue.  I also tested it on another device, and it is reproducible there as well.  It's important that the phone application is terminated, and also that the phone call is actually answered.  After answering, wait a few seconds for the call to continue then end the call from the receiving side.

Comment: I can reproduce this too.  iPhone 5s running 7.1.1